# Running a function on a separately allocated stack

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, stack

I am trying to run a function on a separately allocated stack.

I want to keep the stack for later so I can restore it and resume the function.

The following code compiles and runs, but nothing prints to the screen.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <csetjmp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

unsigned char stack[65535];
unsigned char *base_ptr = stack + 65535 - 1;

unsigned char *old_stack;
unsigned char *old_base;

void function()
{
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    __asm
    {
        mov old_base, ebp
        mov old_stack, esp

        mov ebp, base_ptr
        mov esp, base_ptr

        call function

        mov ebp, old_base
        mov esp, old_stack
    }
}
```

using vs2012/win8/intel Q9650

Comment: Maybe `setjmp`/`longjmp` may be useful for your problem?

Comment: setjmp/longjmp doesn't preserve the stack, only the cpu registers. So if you longjmp out of a function, the local vars can be overwritten.

Comment: You don't tell us which compiler you are using. With one supporting MASM-style assembly, I would write `mov ebp,[base_ptr]` and `mov esp,[base_ptr]`.

Comment: wouldn't [base_ptr] be equivalent to (*base_ptr) ?

Comment: @albundy - It depends on the assembler's syntax. You have to express the equivalent of `&base_ptr`, `base_ptr`, and `*base_ptr`. Which one do you get here? It depends! To get C style `eax = *base_ptr;` you have to do both `mov eax,[base_ptr]` and `mov eax,[eax]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I don't see any problem with your code.
Your sample taken as-is compiles, links and runs as expected.

Perhaps your problem with console settings, or some global STL/CRT initialization or whatever. Anyway, you may put a breakpoint inside your `function` to ensure you're getting there.

Comment: very strange........ I just changed the platform toolset from "Visual Studio 11 (v110)" to "Visual Studio 2010 (v100)" and now it's working =/

Comment: @albundy maybe VS11 can't fit in 64K of stack. Try a) increasing stack size; b) compiling with optimizationsl; c) using printf instead of cout.

Comment: @Igor Skochinsky: Right point (though it seems weird not to fit a 64K stack for a display string output function call chain). Normally a stack has at its top an inaccessible page, so that its access causes stack overflow or access violation exception. Whereas exceeding this custom "stack" will just overwrite some global data or something like this...

Comment: @valdo: iostreams is probably the most bloated (and, IMO, awkward and useless) part of standard C++. I would not be surprised at all if it manages to run over 64KB, especially with optimizations off.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to C++ and name mangling. Function names in C++ are mangled by the compiler (such that using gcc function becomes _Z8functionv for me). This is to facilitate function overloading. The compiler keeps track of the actual names that it has given the different functions in the background so you aren't aware of it. This is a problem for any other language that tries to interact with C++.

This code won't link on my computer.

The solutions:
1) compile with g++ and pass the -S flag (so g++ -S test.cpp). And then take a look at the assembly output (cat test.s) to see what the function is called. Then change the name in "call function" to be "call _Z8functionv" (for me - it could easily be different for you).
2) use C: change the cout << to a printf statement and the above should work.

I take it that you aren't using gcc though (as the assembler is back to front for gas - I had to switch all the operands on the assembler around).

Comment: I put a breakpoint in function(), and it is being called. I can even step through the cout code =/

Comment: almost your code: http://pastebin.com/JsFQSAsy, compile with g++, and runs, prints out "Hello World". What environment are you using (compiler/OS/machine)?

Comment: and the program "int main() {cout << "Hello World" << endl;}" (with appropriate includes) is working fine and produces the output you expect? I'd suspect that if function is getting called then "Hello World" is printed, then the program exits before you can see anything.

Comment: couldn't compile. vs2012 doesn't seem to support asm(""), only __asm{}

Comment: But the question author didn't complain about linker problem! IT builds ok, but doesn't do what's expected

Comment: But it does do what he expects when I compile it using g++ (I had to change things around a bit because gcc and vs do inline assembler differently). So it's something to do with the environment.

Comment: That won't compile with vs2012. But it does under g++/linux. And it works. And it's identical to your code (just changed the syntax of the inline assembler). So either: (1) vs2012 has  bug, or (2) it is printing but then exiting before you see it. Can you confirm that the simple "Hello World" program executes correctly?

Answer (score 1):

According to Intel's x86 documentation for `MOV`, page 3-403, you should load the `SS` register immediately before loading a new `ESP` value. That blocks any interrupts from running until `ESP` has been assigned.

Comment: That's for synchronization if you are going to load *both* SS and ESP. Doesn't happen here.

Comment: that is not the impression I get when reading the doc.  I read it as saying you have to set SS before ESP so interrupts cannot run while ESP in not in a stable state.  Setting SS blocks all interrupts from running until the next instruction is finished executing.

Comment: Your interpretation  is correct if you want to change *both* SS and ESP. The original 8086 didn't have this feature, so there was the risk of a race condition when moving the stack. Here we just change ESP with a single instruction. Then there is no risk, since an interrupt can only happen *between* instructions, not during.