# How to allocate a separate stack for a function manually in C++?

Tags: c++, assembly, memory, x86-64, stack-memory

I am trying to allocate a new stack on the heap in C++ for a function using VirtualAlloc. While debugging, I noticed that the rsp value for my function can either increase or decrease relative to the rsp value that goes into the function. But below the memory allocated via VirtualAlloc is NO_ACCESS protected memory, which means that if I set the rsp value to the address returned by VirtualAlloc, a crash will occur because the function will try to access memory it doesn't have access to.
I don't think it's safe to write an address like "allocated_address + (allocated_size / 2)" to the rsp, so I need a safer way to allocate memory for the local stack.

I tried allocating memory with _malloca, and below the address this function returns is memory with the same protection attributes as the returned address. But then I don't understand how safe it is, and what does _malloca return, "stack top address" or "base address", and if it is the base address, how can I get a stack top address that I can set in rsp? allocated_address + (allocated_size - 1)?

Comment: To answer the question title ... you don't. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: x86-64 stack is the "decrement full" type: grows downwards and `rsp` points to the last used slot. As such initial `rsp` can be just outside the allocated area so `allocated_address + allocated_size`. It's unclear what you mean by _"noticed that the rsp value for my function can either increase"_ ... it can not increase above the initial value, if it does that is a bug.

Comment: I too would like to know why you want to do this, but do you know about [fibers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/fibers)?  I did once do something along these lines but that was on an Apple II, which had no threading support, so I needed to schedule my 'threads' manually (which is what fibers do).

Comment: (And each 'thread' needed its own stack, of course)

Comment: @PaulSanders Unfortunately I don't know about "fibers", I need this in order to write my library for native hooking of Java methods

Comment: @Jester Thank you for the information, I will check the registers again

Comment: @ChrisMM I've done this before, but last time it wasn't safe and my Java application would crash sometimes because of it

Comment: _I need this in order to write my library for native hooking of Java methods_ And you need this because...?  (Just curious.)  Or are you just exploring?

Comment: Windows does not support custom stack allocation. The only supported stack-changing mechanism is fibers.

Comment: _Unfortunately I don't know about "fibers"_ - time to learn?

Comment: @PaulSanders It gives potential in developing plugins for apps, I guess you could call it exploring.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks, I will look into this issue. I need something like this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790008/running-a-function-on-a-separately-allocated-stack) but with normal memory allocation for the stack. I don't mean handing over control over this stack to the operating system

Comment: *but with a better way to allocate memory that could be used as a stack (I misread your message first). Well and as far as I know, _alloca can allocate memory on the stack. In my case I don't care whether it is memory on the stack or on the heap, the main thing is that the function should work with this memory section as with the stack, if I set the rsp register to the allocated address